# Prove angles of $(\vec r), (\vec v),(\vec a)$ are constant in this trajectory

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics

Given the trajectory

$$r(t)=[A\cos(\omega t),B\sin(\omega t+\alpha)]$$

Prove that the angles between $\vec{r}, \vec{v}, \vec{a}$ are constant.

So the first idea is looking at the dot product and then (hopefully) $\cos(\theta), \theta$ being the angle of vectors, wouldn't have a time dependence. However doing all the *extensive* work it doesn't quite work. How could I do this?

Comment: two times differentiate concludes $a=r''=-w^2r$ then $a\parallel r$.

Comment: Certainly true for $\vec{a}, \vec{r}$ although I don't see it for $\vec{v}$ and the other two

Comment: $a\parallel r$ so you just need to prove for $r$ and $v$.

Comment: Exactly, the issue is proving it for $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$ :/

Comment: This appears to be false on the face of it. The path is an ellipse, for which the angle between radial and tangent vectors is not constant.